# Hard drive for Fusion drive: 7200 vs 5400

Tags: hard-drive, mac-mini, fusion-drive

I have a Mac Mini 2012 with 128 GB SSD on board. I want to buy an additional 1TB hard drive and transform the storage to Fusion Drive.

My Mac use case is running Virtual Machines and Docker containers.

What type of hard drive should I choose: 5400rpm or 7200rpm?
Will 5400rpm affect the performance in case of Fusion Drive?
Will Power Nap trigger the HD spin-up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fusion Drives store everything on disk, but keep a cache of most used data on flash.

If you are planning on using a lot of different data (like starting, stopping, creating and removing those docker containers and VMs) then the disk part will be used a lot.

I don't know how much the price difference is where you are, but in regards to RAM and disk, I always go for the fastest. I also use lots of VMs and containers and with those big, continually replaced and changing files, I take all the speed I can get.